# Doctrine ODM: add operator does not accept an object as an operand

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use Doctrine ODM to interact with my mongo database, and I'm trying to use this mongo query that runs without a problem in MongoDB CLI:

```
db.products.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match:  {highEndEmployees: {$lt: 2001 }, lowEndEmployees: {$gt: 1400} }
    },
    {
        $project: { 
            lowEndFinalPrice: {
                $add: [
                        { $multiply: ["$priceMultiplierUser", "$lowEndUsers"] },
                        { $multiply: ["$priceMultiplierEmployee", "$lowEndEmployees"] },
                        { $multiply: ["$priceMultiplierJobOpenings", "$lowEndJobOpenings"] },
                        "$priceBase"
                    ]
            },
            pricePerUser: {$multiply: ["$priceMultiplierUser", "$lowEndUsers"]}, 
            pricePerEmployee: {$multiply: ["$priceMultiplierEmployee", "$lowEndEmployees"]},
            pricePerJobOpening: {$multiply: ["$priceMultiplierJobOpenings", "$lowEndJobOpenings"]},
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { lowEndFinalPrice: 1 }
    }
]);
```

In Doctrine ODM, that query would translate to:

```
    array(
          "aggregate" => "products",
          "pipeline" => array(
              array('$match' =>
                  array(
                    "highEndEmployees" => array('$lt' => 2001),
                    "lowEndEmployees" =>  array('$gt'=> 1400)
                  )
              ),
              array('$project' => array(
                  'lowEndFinalPrice' => array(
                      '$add' => '$priceBase',
                      '$add' => array(
                          '$multiply' => array('$priceMultiplierUser', '$lowEndUsers')
                      )
                  )
              ))
          )
        )
    );
```

But if I try to run that query, I get the following error:

`exception: the $add operator does not accept an object as an operand`

However, if I remove this line:

```
                      '$add' => array(
                          '$multiply' => array('$priceMultiplierUser', '$lowEndUsers')
                      )
```

From the array, the query runs perfectly. So I'm using that that mongo complains when I'm trying to nest another array within the `$add` key.

What is the right way to write the query above in PHP+Doctrine ODM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty straight forward. The problem was in the way I was building the BSON in PHP to send it over to MongoDB.

For example, the following part:

```
             array(
                  '$add' => '$priceBase',
                  '$add' => array(
                      '$multiply' => array('$priceMultiplierUser', '$lowEndUsers')
                  )
```

the second '$add'  overrides the first one, thus not only creating an invalid formula, but also creating the wrong BSON.

It should be like this:

```
             array(
                  '$add' => array(
                      '$basePrice',
                        array(
                            '$multiply' => array('$priceMultiplierUser', '$lowEndUsers')
                        )
                  )
```

So that, when using `json_encode` on that array, I end up with something like this:

```
            $add: [
                    "$priceBase",
                    { $multiply: ["$priceMultiplierJobOpenings", "$lowEndJobOpenings"] }
                ]
```

Which is a valid BSON aggregation in MongoDB